# Xamarin Forms App Fails to Deploy to Android After Adding AndroidX Migration Packages, error MSB4018 Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-support-library, androidx

I recently added the AndroidX migration nugget packages to my Xamarin.Android project, within my Xamarin.Forms solution. I followed the following links for migrating to AndroidX:

1. [Introduction to AndroidX for Xamarin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-for-xamarin/)
2. [Link to AndroidX NuGet Packages used in the project](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22AndroidX%22%20Authors%3A%22Microsoft%22)

I had to add the AndroidX migration packages one-by-one to match the Android.Support libraries and rebuild the project till there are no more build errors. However, when I try to deploy the app to my Android device/emulator I get the following error:

```
k/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2283,3): error MSB4018: The "GenerateJavaStubs" task failed unexpectedly.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2283,3): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2283,3): error MSB4018: File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll'
```

Please also refer to the following link for the detailed build output from Visual Studio:
[App's build output from Visual Studio](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vU5rwJY6NVQz1pent_1dOOvS_1ZlBE-F)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you remove the Xamarin.Android.Support.* packages from the project? You need to keep them if you are using the "migration process"... from the docs `...Keep the Xamarin.Android.Support.* NuGet packages...`.

Comment: @SushiHangover No I did not remove any Xamarin.Android.Support.* packages, they are still in my project. I will update the question with that information

Comment: do you have `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` and `Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration`?

Comment: They are in preview still, so I doubt their guaranteedness

Comment: @Prateek The comment I made above states that I did not remove Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat. All the support packages are still there

Comment: @Prateek any other suggestions?

Comment: @SushiHangover have you managed to successfully migrate to AndroidX?

Comment: I would suggest you to raise an issue at their [github repo](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinAndroidXMigration/issues)

Comment: i would take a look if you share complete code so that I can debug